# Verify an error message using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to verify the error message displaying after login failed. Specifically, I want to verify the text with "Invalid username or password".

This is the html code.

```html
<div id="statusMsg">
  <div class="alert in fade alert-error" style="opacity: 1;">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
      Invalid username or password
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I tried.

```java
String actualMsg=driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='statusMsg']/div")).getText()
String errorMsg= "× Invalid username or password";

if(actualError.equals(errorMsg)) {
    System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
}else{
    System.out.println("Test Case Failed");
};
```

The output is always "Test Case Failed".

Is There a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the text **`Invalid username or password`** you have to reach to the `<div>` tag as follows :

```
String actualMsg = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='statusMsg']/div[@class='alert in fade alert-error']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Next your expected error message is :

```
String errorMsg = "× Invalid username or password";
```

As **`x`** is within `<a>` tag and **`Invalid username or password`** is within `<div>` tag the validation process will need a bit of `String` manipulation. To make the validation simpler you can reduce the expected error message as follows :

```
String errorMsg = "Invalid username or password";
```

Now you can use the following code block to verify if the **`actualMsg`** contains **`errorMsg`** as follows :

```
if(actualMsg.contains(errorMsg)) 
{
    System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
}else
{
    System.out.println("Test Case Failed");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside div you only have text "Invalid username or password", but you are verifying "× Invalid username or password".
First print text from String actualMsg and then put correct errorMsg.

```
String actualMsg = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='statusMsg']/div")).getText()
String errorMsg= "Invalid username or password";

if(actualError.equals(errorMsg)) {
        System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Test Case Failed");
    }
```

;